# How can I connect Watson Conversation to my webapp (github) using liberty.java?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, watson-conversation

How can I connect watson conversation to my webapp(github) using liberty.java? Can someone give me the detailed coding please. Right now I have this:

```
public class Conversation {
    ConversationService service = new ConversationService("2016-12-06");
service.setUsernameAndPassword("uname","pass");
    MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText("Hi").build();

    String workspaceId = "wsId";

    MessageResponse response = service.message(workspaceId, newMessage).execute();
System.out.println(response);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see an existing SDK in Java where you create an example with the Watson conversation and Retrieve and Rank Service here:

Link Github: [Project Java Conversation](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-enhanced)
Link Github (NodeJS): [Project Node JS](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/)

In the 2 examples have one conversation and you can modify what you want.

More information, documentation here:
**Link:** [Java example SDK](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?java#authentication)
**Link:** [Node JS](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?node#authentication)

If you want to use only Conversation in the SDK Java, you can comment the lines of [ProxyResource.java](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-enhanced/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/apis/conversation_enhanced/rest/ProxyResource.java#L125) from #125, that will force the app to never call R&R and always return the Conversation response.

Comment: how do I display it in html?

Comment: In that case, you can use simple conversation in the link I've edited now. This SDK is in Node.js and you can also modify what you want, in my case I found it simpler since I make my changes in the index.html that is inside the Public folder.

Answer (score 0):

I can work on a little proof of concept for you on the weekend, but basically, the usual way you'll need are these steps:

1. Use the web UI to create the conversation backend, providing the logical paths of your conversation
2. In the Liberty runtime, use Watson Java SDK as the middleware between your chat interface and the conversation backend. I suggest you to use Bluemix integration with GIT and DevOps for that
3. In the frontend, you need some chat interface. Nowadays, the most popular chat interface are mobile platforms, and then you have lots of options, and I suggest you to try Telegram. But of course, you can code your own chat window using servlet+sessions or any other technology you're comfortable with (I myself like Primefaces+JSF since they already have a "console" component for that)

Another popular approach is to use Node-Red instead of the Liberty runtime, since it's easy to integrate and to prototype. About this approach, a simple google search will return lots of links, but this one seems to be a good starting point -- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/hickmat/entry/Telegram_frontend_for_Watson_using_NodeRED?lang=en

About Liberty+GIT+DevOps, I recommend this tutorial -- https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/bluemix-watson-apis-quickstart-using-java-sdk-version-2016/

Comment: I am actually using Java Cloudant Web Starter, Node red is not appropriate for me. I just need help with the connection(watson conversation) & display it in html. @Leo

Comment: I've sent you an email with some code, pls take a look and tell me if it helps. good luck

Comment: I was asked by my superior not to use Cloudant. Will I be able to connect Watson Conversation to phpmyadmin? Is it possible?

Comment: I am not sure but I think Watson Conversation does not need any explicit storage, I think the component stores its entities internally